# firefox can not open remote file link

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

In HTML, there is a link to remote file href="file://///remote_server_ip/filename",

When I click it should open the file, which is working perfectly file in IE, but it doesn't work in firefox

How can I fix that?

Comment: I am using Firefox Quantum version 13.1.1 (43120) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

See [Links to local pages do not work](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work):

> For security purposes, Mozilla applications block links to local files (and directories) from remote files. This includes linking to files on your hard drive, on mapped network drives, and accessible via Uniform Naming Convention (UNC) paths.

The page goes on to explain a few ways that a **user** can modify **their specific instance** of Firefox to allow local links from remote files.